# Xcode tools getting working without the Xcode CD or external drive?

Tags: install, xcode, development, developer-program

I would like to get the Xcode-developer things to my Macs. I noticed that Apple has started to offer some terminal things online, more [here](https://developer.apple.com/opensource/). I am still lazy to get the CDs, to get all Xcode-developer things, is there some easy way to do it online without the Xcode CD? Is there any way to get all Xcode things pre-installed so not to waste time for their installation?

Comment: I'm confused - do you have a mac or [do you not have a Mac](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65997/xcode-for-ipad)?

Comment: @bmike it is not a question here. The question is historical because Apple did not earlier provide Xcode online, only on CD. It is solved.

Comment: Thank you for cleaning this up. Simple, clear minimal questions really help the site be useful as a reference.

Comment: @bmike agree with that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode hasn't come on physical media for a long time now. These days, you can download it directly from the Mac App Store:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12