# Xcode for iPad?

Tags: ipad, xcode, development, unix

I don't have an Apple computer, only iPad and Debian computer but I still would like to add a feature to iOS app [here](https://bitbucket.org/gvol/sage-iphone-app/issue/1/add-sharing-option-to-the-right-corner-of). Earlier I found out that I can download Xcode, more [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65832/xcode-tools-getting-working-without-the-xcode-cd-or-external-drive), from Apple Store. Now I cannot find Xcode from Apple Store in iPad. I want to get this one [here](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) for iPad so how can I get Xcode for iPad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You currently cannot install Xcode on an iPad or iPhone, or any device other than a mac running OSX. There have been discussions & questions asked about it before; basically you shouldn't hold your breath.

If you have a mac you can always consider VNC if you want to do work remotely on your iPad, but to me it sounds like you don't have a mac and were hoping the iPad could serve as your development environment.

Comment: `"If you have a mac you can always consider VNC if you want to do work remotely on your iPad, but to me it sounds like you don't have a mac and were hoping the iPad could serve as your development environment."` <--- I cannot understand this, could you clarify? Yes, I try to use iPad as a development environment and I don't have a mac (only iPad).

Comment: Is it sufficient to buy any old mac for development? Like old Macbook air?

Comment: @hhh Yes. Provided the machine you purchase meets the requirements for Xcode (e.g., OS X 10.7.4 or later), you can use any Mac for development.

Comment: Can you recommend some VNC client? Screens? iSSH? I have never really understand what VNC really is, why not just SSH with XY -flags? Moved [here](http://superuser.com/questions/482477/vnc-over-ssh-with-xy-flags).

Comment: I believe that either Screens or iSSH have gotten good reviews and are regarded as quality software. Looks like Screens is more user friendly, but you would get more power use out of iSSH, so choose what you think suits your style best :)

As for why not ssh -x straight from the iPad: you may be able to... I've never tried, but I think it'd take a bit more setup and work to get to work correctly than is worth just grabbing an app and letting the developer worry about that.

Answer (score 5):

**Xcode is an IDE available exclusively for the Mac OS operating system.** There is no mobile version of the software. The link you provided is to the Mac App Store, which is its own separate entity from the App Store for iOS devices.

Comment: ...iPad does not have Mac OS operation system?

Comment: iPad runs iOS; Mac runs OS X. While they have some common code, they are different operating systems.

Comment: @hhh It does in a way. iOS is a much smaller, streamlined version of the Mac OS operating system that's optimized for Apple's line of mobile devices.

Comment: To quote the **[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS)**: "iOS is derived from OS X, with which it shares the Darwin foundation, and is therefore a Unix operating system. iOS is Apple's mobile version of the OS X operating system used on Apple computers."

Comment: You mean that Xcode does not run even with Windows, even though Windows has iTunes?

Comment: @hhh That is correct. The only way that you could run Xcode on a Windows machine is if you were to set up a Virtual Machine running the Mac OS platform, or some other sort of thirt-party workaround. Otherwise, the only official source is via an official Apple system.

Comment: @hhh That's what "XCode is a OS X app" means. iTunes, as a rare exception for Apple, has both an OS X version and a Windows version.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode is a Mac App, not an iOS App. As such, it doesn't run on the iPad. The program you linked to, http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12, is in the **Mac** app store, not the iOS App store.

There might be some confusion because Xcode can be used to **develop** iOS apps, but it itself is a Mac app only.

Answer (score 3):

As with the other answers, you can't directly because OS X and iOS are different platforms with different restrictions and apps (duh).  You can however accomplish what you're attempting to do with an OS X machine running and connected to the Internet in order to compile the builds for your iPad.

This is exactly how the Dringend app works (http://dringend.cc/).  It runs on your iPad as a slimmed-down 3rd-party Xcode replacement (it even understands `.xcodeproj` files!), and uses Xcode via remote OS X host to do the dirty-work.

I thought I read something somewhere about another start-up working towards a product with the same premise, but provides the OS X build-machines as a paid service— I'll update this if I find their name.  Until then, there's always [OS X hosting](https://www.google.com/search?q=os+x+hosting).

Answer (score -2):

The iPad's processor's power is way too small to run Xcode. You can let Apple think about it or just get a Mac.